# How can we solve this recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

My friends and I are having trouble resolving this...

T1 = 1,

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1, n > 1.

I would appreciate if anyone could help us solve this, and explain how to.

Comment: What do you mean by $n/2$ if $n$ is odd?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It would be preferable to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. You can [get started here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and a more complete reference [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @HansLundmark Generally in this kind of "*get the complexity of the algorithm*" type of problems, we do not care about such details (we consider $T$ defined on the reals, but only interested in values taken at integers), in fact we solve for $n=2^p$ and even take the log after. But I agree it would matter if we were to solve this as a true functional equation for integers only.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- set $T(n)=U(n)-1$ to get rid of the constant term $+1$
- set $n=2^p$ and $V(p)=U(n)$ to linearize the equation
- solve for $V$
- get back the chain of substitutions to express $T$ (use $p=\log_2(n)$ if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Considering $n = 2^m$ we have

$$
T\left(2^m\right)=2T\left(2^{m-1}\right)+1
$$

now calling $\mathbb{T}(\cdot)=T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ we have

$$
\mathbb{T}(m)= 2\mathbb{T}(m-1)+1
$$

this linear recurrence has as soluttion

$$
\mathbb{T}(m)= c_0 2^{m-1}+2^m - 1
$$

or equivalently

$$
T\left(2^m\right)=c_0 2^{m-1}+2^m - 1
$$

then

$$
T(n) = c_0 \frac n2 + n - 1 = c_1 n -1
$$

but $T(1) = c_1-1=1\Rightarrow c_1 = 2$ hence

$$
T(n) = 2n-1
$$